# Use CTRL-SPACE to open menu on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I'd like to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to open/close the Linux Mint menu (similar to how <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is used on OS X to show/hide Spotlight).

I tried going to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Cinnamon and setting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> for the key "Menu button". Upon restarting, the key combination doesn't work at all.

This is a vanilla install of Linux Mint 17.

Answer (score 2):

Control-space is used for other things, which may interfere:

- it is used in some applications to trigger an input method (see for example *[How to disable Ctrl-Space selecting chinese keyboard on windows 7? [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/363873/how-to-disable-ctrl-space-selecting-chinese-keyboard-on-windows-7)*)
- in a terminal, it sends an ASCII NULL (a zero), which can confuse applications which handle nul-terminated strings.