# Mate custom shortcut for keyboard layout in Linux Mint 18 (Sarah)

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

Coming from OSX and Windows 7, I want to try to keep the same keyboard shortcuts so that I do not get confused when I switch between them. I have mapped the CTRL key in Windows 7 and Linux Mint to be next to the space-bar.

Next, I need to configure the keyboard shortcut for changing keyboard layouts. In OSX and Windows 7, I use CNTRL+SPACE but in Linux Mint's MATE desktop environment there is no option to specific a custom shortcut.

I switch keyboard layouts frequently, and I particularly like CNTRL+SPACE since it is easy on my hands. So how do I do this?

I have seen [this answer related to Cinnamon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238839/63091) about possible conflicts but that is not an issue for me. I really want this keyboard shortcut.

I am happy to switch to another DE if that is what it takes.

---

EDIT: I can toggle layouts using a little utility called [xkblayout-state](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79030/63091). But how do I run it from MATE? In KDE Plasma, I was successful in creating a shortcut and assigning CTRL+SPACE, and it worked. I don't see how to assign CNTRL+SPACE anywhere in MATE :(

EDIT2: Okay, In MATE Preferences(Control Center)->Keyboard Shortcuts at the bottom, there is an Add button. I put the script containing the command in command field and assigned CONTROL+SPACE as the shortcut. Nothing :(

Comment: Write a mini shellscript for switching layouts, and create keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: @IporSircer Good idea. I know how to toggle it from the command line, but where do I assign a keyboard shortcut to it?

Comment: `setxkbmap`, http://www.securitronlinux.com/bejiitaswrath/some-useful-tips-for-the-linux-mate-desktop/